# Linux ubuntu system command `sudo python (file_name).py` not working

Tags: command-line, python

Linux ubuntu system command `sudo python (file_name).py` not working

> python: can't open file '/home/joy/fe_dir/The_one_i_want.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

I just check my `/fe_dir` directory contain file `'The_one_I_want (new).py'` and  `The_one_I_want.py` but I couldn't open it

tried command and output：

> (python368) joy@joy-System-Product-Name:~/fe_dir$ sudo python The_one_i_want.py
> python: can't open file '/home/joy/fe_dir/The_one_i_want.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

(python368) joy@joy-System-Product-Name:~/fe_dir$ python The_one_i_want.py
python3: can't open file 'The_one_i_want.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

(python368) joy@joy-System-Product-Name:~/fe_dir$ ls
'The_one_I_want (new).py'   The_one_I_want.py

(python368) joy@joy-System-Product-Name:~/fe_dir$ pwd
/home/joy/fe_dir

(python368) joy@joy-System-Product-Name:~/fe_dir$ pwd -P
/home/joy/fe_dir

(python368) joy@joy-System-Product-Name:~/fe_dir$ ^C

(python368) joy@joy-System-Product-Name:~/fe_dir$ sudo python /fe_dir/The_one_i_want.py
[sudo] joy 的密碼：
python: can't open file '/fe_dir/The_one_i_want.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Comment: Please do not show pictures of text, cut and paste the text into the body of the question. Please EDIT the question and add this info. BTW have you tried giving a full path to the location of the file in your attempts?

Comment: you run sudo - run python in root context, first it is very likely you run a different python than the one in your virtualenv, second you can just test if in root context the file is accessible by running `sudo ls -l /path/to/yourfile`, it could be that it is located on a nfs filesystem where root has no access for example... in any case it should give you more ideas.

Comment: hi, @David, I just edit and removed pic with text. And reply to @mestia I just input `$ sudo ls -l /path/to/The_one_I_want.py` and the out is still the same with
`ls: 無法存取 '/path/to/The_one_I_want.py': 沒有此一檔案或目錄`

Comment: The command `ls 'The_one_I_want (new).py'`  can _never_ give `The_one_I_want.py` as output.

Answer (score 0):

`The_one_i_want.py` and the file you have, `The_one_I_want.py` are different file names (spot the difference).

Comment: I just try `$ sudo python /fe_dir/The_one_I_want.py ` too, shows `python: can't open file '/fe_dir/The_one_I_want.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory`

Comment: Copy the file name and path from the terminal, paste it into your command line, and surround the path with single quotes.

Answer (score 0):

after I find my file path by `sudo find / -type f -name "The_one_I_want.py"` 
I ran the .py file again`sudo python '/home/joy/fe_dir/The_one_I_want.py'`
, and at least now is execute the file

the code and out put:

> (base) joy@joy-System-Product-Name:~$ sudo find / -type f -name

> "The_one_I_want.py" find: ‘/run/user/1000/doc’: 拒絕不符權限的操作
> find:
> ‘/run/user/1000/gvfs’: 拒絕不符權限的操作
> /home/joy/fe_dir/The_one_I_want.py
>
> (base) joy@joy-System-Product-Name:~$ sudo python'/home/joy/fe_dir/The_one_I_want.py'
>
> hello
> /home/joy
>
> ```
> ['.bash_logout',
> ```
>
> '模板', 'tutorial_env', 'snap', '.config', '.chewing', 'miniconda3',
> '.cache', '.bash_history', '.conda', '.vscode', '.nv', '下載', '.ssh',
> 'fe_dir', '.profile', '.java', '.pki', '文件', '音樂', '影片', '桌面',
> '.local', '.bashrc', '.python_history', '圖片', '.gnupg',
> '.sudo_as_admin_successful', '公共',
> 'Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh'] False